# How can I change style function with using not in js?

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I have this code in CSS:

```
body > *:not(#error-login) {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

And now I want this place in JavaScript I don`t know how.

Comment: You can use `document.querySelectorAll("body > *:not(#error-login)")` to get a list of matching elements. Iterate over them and set their `.style.filter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("body > *:not(#error-login)");
console.log(Array.from( nodes ));

for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
  nodes[i].style.filter = "blur(5px)";
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
<a id="blah">blah</a>
<span id="error-login">error-login</span>
<span id="not-error-login">not-error-login</span>
```